# Creating tokens with random value

Tags: petri-net, cpn-tools

In the petrinet shown below i have a problem creating tokens with random value in place input2, since the rand() function doesn't seem to  work. Is there any other way to do it?
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

CPN ML provides random choice of color for **small** color sets. You could use `SmallInt.ran()` for a random integral number in the range [1,10].

`REAL` is not a small color set and if you were to use `REAL.ran()` you would get an exception.

I would guess that a suitable solution for your example would be to use `1.0/real(SmallInt.ran())`.

I do not have a copy of CPN Tools at hand so please take the above advice critically.